# generalizations of the linearly independence of column vectors in a Vandemonde matrix to higher dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant, matrix-rank

Let $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n\in\mathbb{R} $  or $\mathbb{C}$. By the non-degeneracy of Vandemonde matrix

[image]

the maps

$$
f: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n,$$   $$
x\longmapsto (1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^{n-1})
$$
and
$$
f:\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n-1},
$$
$$
z\longmapsto (1,z,z^2,\cdots,z^{n-1})
$$
satisfy the condition:

***(C)***  ***for any distinct $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n$, their images are linearly independent***.

**Question:** For $m\geq 3$, how to construct maps

$$
f: \mathbb{R}^m\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m(n-1)+1}
$$

satisfying condition **(C)** ?